# Rescue NameError just in this class

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

I've got a Ruby script and I'm doing this

```
module MyModule
    class MyClass
        def do_something
            begin
                deployer_object = Object.const_get("MyModule").const_get("#{class_name}Deployer").new(@config, @directory).deploy
            rescue NameError => e
                MyModule::Logger.error("Error loading the deployer #{class_name}. This deployer it's not installed!")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now it rescues all the NameError exceptions in this class and the one loaded in the fifth line as well. How can I make it so it only rescues exceptions in MyModule::MyClass and not in the one being initialized in the 5th line? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pack everything inside a `begin` once again. This works in the same manner:

```
module MyModule
    class MyClass
        def do_something
            deployer_object = Object.const_get("MyModule").const_get("#{class_name}Deployer").new(@config, @directory).deploy
        rescue NameError => e
            MyModule::Logger.error("Error loading the deployer #{class_name}. This deployer it's not installed!")
        end
    end
end
```

I don't fully understand your question. What are you trying to rescue from? You don't want to catch exceptions from  `Deployer's` initializer?